# workflow warnings

Tags: c#, workflow, warnings

I'm trying to clean up the warnings being generated by some existing code.  I'm stuck on these 3... I really have no experience with workflows, so I have no idea what it's complaining about... any ideas?

```
warning WF1820: Activity 'StartWorkflowActivity' validation warning:
Validation failed for parameter 'workflowName'. All parameters for
the receive activity should have a valid activity binding or a value
specified.

warning WF1820: Activity 'ContinueWorkflowActivity' validation warning:
Validation failed for parameter 'workflowContext'. All parameters for
the receive activity should have a valid activity binding or a value
specified.

warning WF1821: Activity 'ContinueWorkflowActivity' validation warning:
Validation failed for parameter '(ReturnValue)'. No valid activity bind
or value found specified for return value.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your workflow runs properly, you shouldn't have anything to worry about - it will give you a warning for properties that are bound at runtime (and thus not set in the code).

Comment: OK, but I still want to get rid of all my warnings.  It won't even let me disable it using
    #pragma warning
It says that it's not a valid warning number